# flowing elements as usual after an absolute within relatively positioned element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overlay two elements on top of each other:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <input style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 3px;">
        XXXX-XX-XXX
    </div>
</div>
```

So far so good... the two elements overlay fine, and this will work regardless of where on the page the DIV goes in the flow.  But then I go to add the next element to the page:

```
<div>
PART 2 GOES HERE ABCDEFG
</div>
```

Uh oh, we have a problem!  The next element gets placed *under* the previous one. How do I get subsequent content back into the normal static flow?  The rest of the content can't have to know about this special element, i.e. if the element with the overlay is inserted anywhere in the document it should behave the same as if it was a single element of the same size.

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcf2kuvw/1/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Any reason you don't just use the html `placeholder` attribute to accomplish all of this without any positioning trickery? `<input type=text placeholder=xxxx-xx-xxx>`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes.  The placeholder disappears as soon as anything is typed.

Comment: That is a good thing and leads to be better overall UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Santi points out, the content of absolutely positioned elements does not actually contribute to setting the `height` of the element. But, instead of setting a specific value for `height` (which may not be correct for all viewports), you can just change the `input` style to be `position:relative` so that it's height will be set. Then, you can position the overlay on top of it.

```html
<div>
Content that goes first.
</div>
<div style="position: relative;">
        <input style="position: relative;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 3px;">
            XXXX-XX-XXX
        </div>
</div>
<div>
    PART 2 GOES HERE ABCDEFG
</div>
```

Now, it should be said that you should avoid using inline styles as they create spaghetti code, don't promote code reuse and are difficult to override later, if you need to and, it seems that what you are actually trying to do can be done with basic HTML and no CSS at all:

```html
<div>
Content that goes first.
</div>
<div>
        <input placeholder="xxxx-xxx-xxx">
</div>
<div>
    PART 2 GOES HERE ABCDEFG
</div>
```

Comment: I think when OP says "below", he actually means *"behind"*. His example shows that the relatively-positioned element is actually *covering* the following content.

Comment: Could be, but then the OP asks how to get the subsequent content back into the normal static flow.

Comment: This is true, but OP also says: "If the element with the overlay is inserted anywhere in the document *it should behave the same as if it was a single element of the same size.*" - This leads me to believe that OP wants any element after to position itself as if the `relative` div was just a regular div.

Answer (score 2):

Elements that are positioned using `position: absolute;` won't take up any actual height. Your `position: relative;` div will now also have a height of 0, because none of its children occupy any height.

By simply adding a height to this div, your elements should behave as you expect:

```html
<div>
Content that goes first.
</div>
<div style="position: relative; height: 25px;">
        <input style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 3px;">
            XXXX-XX-XXX
        </div>
</div>
<div>
    PART 2 GOES HERE ABCDEFG
</div>
```

**EDIT:** If you don't want a forced-height, you might be better off with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43551293/2026606) by [Scott Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695364/scott-marcus).

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it forces you ti pick a value for height that may not be correct in all viewports.

Comment: Sure, but being that OP is absolutely-positioning text to fit within a text box using pixel-specific `top` and `left` values, I was under the impression that changing viewports wasn't a primary concern. I think we're in agreement here that OP might have been better off describing *why* he/she wants to do this, instead of being so specific - they might just be after a simple `placeholder`, as you commented.

Comment: thanks for the explanation of *why* this is happening.